# logical_date not available when executing Airflow task

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a Python Operator containing a BigQueryInsertJobOperator:

```py
default_args={
    'owner': 'myself',
    'start_date': '2024-02-14',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 0
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_test_dag',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    default_args=default_args
)

def create_tables():
    tables_to_create = Variable.get('list_of_tables')

    for table in tables_to_create:
        create_table_task = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
            dag=dag,
            task_id=f'create_{table}_table',
            configuration={
                "query": {
                    "my_query"
                }
            }
        )

        create_table_task.execute(dict())

create_new_tables = PythonOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='my_task_id',
    python_callable=create_tables
)
```

If I run it like this it will throw a `KeyError` on `create_table_task.execute(dict())` for `logical_date`. Now, if my understanding is correct the `logical_date` should be the same as `execution_date` and gets defined when the task is executed.

Why does the operator's context still asks for it?